# how to allow span inside p (ckeditor)

Tags: wysiwyg

I have a paragragh which has 3 font colors throughout it, however every time I try to add the spans inside the paragraph CKEditor takes it upon it's self to remove them on me. How do I get the spans to stay inside the paragraph?

I save this:

```
<p>Have <span class="lt-blue-txt">TROUBLING SYMPTOMS</span> and health concerns taken over your life? <span class="white-txt">Muse can help</span>.</p>
```

but it turns into this:

```
<p>Have TROUBLING SYMPTOMS and health concerns taken over your life? Muse can help.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did these links not help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349048/ckeditor-strips-span-and-style-attributes

"If you are using the CKeditor module then there is an option in Advanced Options that is also mentioned in the module homepage where you should set"

or:
[Prevent WYSIWYG+CKEditor from stripping html classes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90710/prevent-wysiwygckeditor-from-stripping-html-classes)
"There is an issue with CKEditor 4.1+, which has a feature called Automatic Content Filter (ACF) that will automatically strip attributes not defined for the editor"